# Which ferry from China to South Korea is the cheapest?

Tags: budget, china, ferries, south-korea

In less than two weeks my Chinese visa will expire and I'm considering taking one of the ferries to South Korea.

I don't care about which part of China it leaves from, there are several choices. I will buy the cheapest one-way ticket, I don't care if it means sleeping in a shared cabin, or even just getting a seat. Whatever is cheapest is fine. I also don't care where in Korea it lands, how long it takes, etc.

Wikivoyage has a bit of info on [China to Korea](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/China#South_Korea) and [Korea to China](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/South_Korea#By_boat), but I haven't been able to find something with all the prices so I can choose the cheapest. These are the places I can find which have ferries departing to South Korea, all to Incheon:

- [Dalian, Liaoning](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dalian#By_boat)
- [Dandong, Liaoning](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dandong#By_boat)
- Lianyungang, Shandong
- [Qingdao, Shandong](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Qingdao#By_boat)
- Rizhao, Shandong
- Rongcheng, Shandong
- Tanggu
- [Tianjin](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tianjin#By_boat)
- [Weihai, Shandong](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Weihai#Boat)

---

**UPDATE** I just found [an excellent map of ferry routes](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=110246379491624515614.0004699e61c9f03619453) by chance Googling, but I don't know anything about it and it doesn't include prices.

Comment: It looked like a textbook shopping question to me. There are many different routes and many different classes of service, and with currency fluctuations and inflation in China, I wouldn't expect prices to be stable for more than a single season.

Comment: You need to read [the textbook on shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) again. We've long supported objective "cheapest" questions but not ones like "cheapest flight from X to Y on date Z". Almost anything can fluctuate. I specifically say "cheapest" and I don't care about the other factors so only the cheapest class is relevant. Currency fluctuations don't affect which option will be cheapest. I would expect the shorter routes serviced by the slower ferries in the less popular places to pretty stably be the cheaper over many seasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two days ago I took the **Weidong ferry from Qingdao** to Incheon, while both the Lonely Planet book and the ferry company web site state 775 CNY as the cheapest fare (economy bed) plus 30 CNY port tax = 805 CNY, the actual ticket was just 458 + 30 = **488 CNY**

[image: ferry ticket]

Both China and South Korea have National holidays soon, so I don't think this was an off-season price.

One of the most interesting part of the sail was going through the locks into port of Incheon:

[image: In the lock]

Comment: That's a bargain! How long did the crossing take? Do you have a photo or any interesting points worth adding?

Comment: Weidong ferry is nice when it leaves as scheduled, but I have bought tickets several times and only once did it depart on the scheduled day. Be prepared for many extra days stay at your hotel.

Comment: How many days have these "many extra days" been roughly?

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ferry companies so multiple rates.

You can take a look at [Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/SouthKorea.htm), which provide the listing.

There is [Weidong](http://www.weidong.com/) which runs about 750 CNY for the economy ticket which runs from Qingdao and [Jinchon Ferry](http://www.jinchon.co.kr/WebTicket_new.asp), which runs from Tanggu.  Unfortunately the latter is in Korean, but there is information on that from [Travel China Guide](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/cruise/tianjin-japankobe/allegrashipcruise/) which states 888 CNY for economy accomodation.

**Additional Info Based on Updated Map**

There is a site called [By Ferry From 2 Japan](http://byferryfrom2japan.com), which lists all the ferrys from [China to Korea](http://byferryfrom2japan.com/en/korea-china) mentioned on that Google Map including pricing.

Comment: I didn't even think of Seat 61 for ferries. I associate it with trains. But I believe there's more than two ferries.

Comment: @hippietrail The information listed as part of the train journey from China to Korea but since traveling land only isn't possible.  Sea travel is a must.

Comment: I guess that makes sense in some way. Do they also cover air travel when that is a must?

Comment: @hippietrail Didn't find any

Comment: Maybe "mustness" isn't their only criteria (-: I'm going to add a list of ferry departure points to make it easier to work on this question ... (For me and anybody else ...)

Comment: @hippietrail "This site explains how to travel comfortably & affordably by train or ferry where you might think that air was now the only option", from the site's front page.

Answer (score 4):

I've been Googling this all day, regularly finding new ports and routes to plug into new searches. Not long after finding the route map that I added to the question I found a page with lots of details and prices. Ironically on [a website named `byferryfrom2japan.com`](http://byferryfrom2japan.com/en/korea-china).

Of all the options the cheapest, as of one year ago, seems to be:

```
Lianyungang >> Pyeongtaek
      dep.                         arr.
Lianyungang port    >>>>     Pyeongtaek port
15:00 Wednesday     >>>>     13:00 (the next day)
15:00 Sunday        >>>>     14:00 (the next day)

*    Vessel: C-K STAR（中韩之星）
*    operator: Yeonunhang Ferry (Korean) Lianyungang C-k Ferry (Chinese)
*    Charges & fees：Economy Class 94,000(KRW) 560(CNY)
                    First class 110,000(KRW) 650(CNY)
                    Business 130,000(KRW) 780(CNY)
                    Royal 155,000(KRW) 920(CNY)
                    Royal Suite class 220,000(KRW) 1,300(CNY)
                    VIP 330,000(KRW) 1,950(CNY)
                    Fuel Surcharge: 20,000(KRW)90(CNY)
                    Departure Tax: Pyeongtaek 3,200(KRW) Lianyungang 30(CNY).
*    Reservation: Contact with their office in Pyeongtaek
                    031-684-3100 (phone) 031-684-3118(fax), in Lianyungang
                    0518-8238-8189(phone) 0518-8238-8935(fax).

updated 25 Jan. 2013
```

That's `CNY` 560 + 90 + 30 = 680. About `USD` $112.50 / `EUR` 82

Answer (score 1):

The Weidong ferry from Qingdao to Incheon, IF it is still this price (488 CNY), it is indeed the cheapest that I know of and converts in US Dollars to $72.15 
This is about (less than) half the price of airfare from Beijing to Seoul.