# Is advance booking required for ferries from China to South Korea?

Tags: china, bookings, ferries, south-korea, no-advance-plans

We already have a [question about prices of ferries from China to South Korea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23217/which-ferry-from-china-to-south-korea-is-the-cheapest), my question is: **can I just show up at the port and buy a ticket for the same-day ferry or do I have to book it in advance?**

I usually never know when I arrive somewhere or in this case when I will be ready to leave China, so ideally I don't want to make any advance bookings except when the prices are significantly cheaper.

I don't have a vehicle and I don't know yet which of the ferry routes I will use.

Comment: Don't you need to have some sort of proof to show you will certainly leave China again, when you apply for your visa? I just applied for my visa last week and I needed to give that info + a copy of my flights. Or do you have multiple entries on your visa and this will just be a temporarily leave?

Comment: So far I entered China three times, but every time overland. I never had an onward ticket and was never asked for one. This may be different at an airport. I will enter China again overland in a few weeks but I haven't got my visa yet.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you can just do that. Just out of curiosity, what do you fill in as itinerary and what do you show them when applying for a visa? Since I had to give my flight tickets (Sorry for the question in the question)

Comment: Thinking about it, all three visas I've done through a travel agency and they never asked for an itinerary. Last year I had to extend my visa while in China and had to give an itinerary. I put down a few major cities and Hong Kong as my exit point. That's always an option.

Comment: It looks like [Weidong Ferry](http://www.weidong.com/servlet/ShowPage?wdid=WE003004000) requires reservations, I see something about "Reservations are valid until 24 hours before departure"... not entirely sure what they mean by "valid" though.

Comment: Surely this depends on availability of tickets?

Comment: I've arrived in China four times, each time overland. Two entries on each of two visas. I did need to show my ticket out of China both times I applied for a visa. I never had to provide an itinerary either when applying for a visa or extending a visa there. There was a space on the form but I left it black and that was not a problem.

Comment: Based on my experience taking ferries between South Korea and Japan six times and China and Taiwan once or twice, I never booked in advance and would be surprised if it's required here either. It's probably possible to book though but I wouldn't guess the ferry is full most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got to Qingdao which is one of several Chinese port cities that have ferries going to South Korea.

I went to the ferry terminal in the morning and managed to get a ticket for the afternoon sail of the same day without a problem.

That doesn't mean the ferry will never be fully booked, but from what I understood, that is not a very common case.

So no advance reservation was required.